# IConfiguration connection string method returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There have been similar questions here regarding this problem, caused by typing or other syntax errors. I've checked it all but cannot get this to work. The configuration does not contain any enviroment variables for the appSettings.json file. Thanks for help.

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalDatabase")));
        services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
}
```

appSettings:

```
{
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "LocalDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13;Database=WebApp2;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

}

Comment: Is your `appsettings.json` file in Visual Studio marked to be copied to the output folder ("Copy always" or "Copy if newer") ? Otherwise, the file just isn't present where the app is running ....

Comment: That was it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The appsettings.json file was not marked to be copied in output folder. Changed it in files properties to Copy if newer.